# Заряд батареи каждый раз выводится на новой строке

Tags: java, android

Нужно выводить заряд батареи на экран что собственно и делаю ,но дальше он должен изменятся в зависимости от уровня ,но у меня он печатает каждый раз заряд друг под другом ...Как  с этим быть ,Кому не сложно помогите

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Context mContext;

    private TextView mTextViewInfo;
    private TextView mTextViewPercentage;

    private int mProgressStatus = 0;
    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,-1);
            mTextViewInfo.setText(mTextViewInfo.getText() + "Battery Level : " + level);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        mContext.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver,iFilter);

        // Get the widgets reference from XML layout
        mTextViewInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_info);
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем строчка `mTextViewInfo.getText()`?

Comment: ```mTextViewInfo.getText()```  возвращает текущий текст в текстовом поле, соответственно не сложно предположить почему у вас добавляется текст с низу а не заменяется старый.

Comment: и вправду зачем я беру сновно текст)))